# Does Snow Leopard put core dumps somewhere special?

Tags: macos, segmentation-fault, osx-snow-leopard, coredump

I'm trying to debug a segfault on an application I'm working on (works on linux of course, so I can't use that as my fallback for debugging core dumps).  Anyhow, I've set "ulimit -c unlimited" and snow leopard reports "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"  but alas there is no core file to be found.  Does Snow Leopard put them somewhere special or is there some other option I need to enable?  Surprisingly little returned when I google this...

Comment: Can you run your application under the debugger (XCode or plain gdb)?

Comment: I can, but it's often a pain, especially if my code is linked into python or something similar.  Other times segfaults aren't reproducible, so I'd like to be able to do post-mortem properly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to configure `launchd` so that it actually writes out the core dumps. You can find instructions for doing so in this [Apple TechNote.](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn2004/tn2124.html#SECCOREDUMPS)

Basically, you need to enable Core Dumps by adding the line:

```
limit core unlimited
```

to your `/etc/launchd.conf` file, creating it if necessary, and then restarting.

You can also enable the core dump for a single terminal session by calling:

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

before you launch your command-line app.

You can find the core dumps in `/cores`. Be careful, as core dumps can be large and can easily fill up your drive if you don't clean out the `/cores` directory on a regular basis.

Comment: Aha! Exactly what I wanted! I wonder why they decided to store them there instead of in the working directory...

Comment: I suspect just so it's easier to clean them out. If core dumps are enabled system-wide you could end up with a lot of large files scattered around the system if they were placed in the working directory.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a wild guess, but did you check `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/`?

Comment: Looks like I _do_ have one I just don't know how to use a computer I guess.  No core files in there though =(

Comment: Also try ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/ for application crash reports. On OS X, the /Library tree is mirrored for each user under ~/Library. If your app runs in user space, OS X will put the crash report under ~/Library.